# How to force laptop to play through built-in speaker even when headphone jack is plugged in?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, speakers, headphone-jack

When I was attempting to take out my headphones I accidentally snapped the metallic connector off, so it became stuck in my computer's headphone jack slot.  As a result, my computer now thinks there are headphones plugged in even though there are none plugged in.  How do I force my laptop to play through the default speakers that are built into it?

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that there is a software/settings fix for this. The vast majority of 3.5 mm headphone jacks have spring-loaded contacts that physically disconnect the built-in speakers when a plug is inserted.

If you can't grab it with a pair of pliers, you will have to open it up to remove the broken plug or bypass the jack.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default playback device by right clicking on the volume icon in your taskbar. Then selecting playback devices. Find the device you wish to use as the default and right click on it in the list of devices and select use as default playback device.